# C++ Recursion and Math

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to write a recursive function to produce the following output:

```
n=1: Output is: 1
n=2: Output is: 1 2 1 
n=3: Output is: 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 
n=4: Output is: 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
```

I was presented with this information as well:

The function will write 2^n-1 integers. Note that the output for n always consists of the output for n-1, followed by n itself, followed by a second copy of the output for n-1.

Currently Used Code:

```
void nth(unsigned int n) {
    if (n <= 1) { return; }
    std::cout << n - 1 << n << n - 1;
    n--;
    nth(n);
}
```

Thank you for any and all help received.

After running the above code I came up with the desired output for only '2' as input. The part of this question that confuses me is the "The function will write 2^n-1 integers."

Please, give me some explanations about how make a recursive algorithm to work properly?

Comment: Don't forget to cite this web site as a source when you turn in the assignment.

Comment: As you can see from the answer, the code does exactly what the question say… It would have been better for you to write it yourself so that you would have learn something. A site like this one is not intended for having other people do our homework.

Comment: Yea I tried writing it out myself @Phil1970

This is what I got and it only worked for one value '2':

`void nth(int n) {
 if (n <= 1) { return; }
 cout << n - 1 << n << n - 1;
 n--;
 nth(n)
}`

Sorry I don't know how to put that in a code block

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me introduce my version of program. It's similar in meaning to реу *OrenIshShalom*'s version, but a bit more efficient and c++-way ))

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string foo(unsigned int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return std::string(" ");
    std::string s_prev = foo(n - 1);
    return s_prev + std::to_string(n) + s_prev;
}


int main()
{
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
        std::cout << "n=" << i << ": Output is:" << foo(i) << std::endl;
}
```

You can try to understand logics of **foo** function from this picture:

[image]

As seen, each next level consists of a combination of the previous level string and the current number **n**, so we can write the approximate variant of function:

```
std::string foo(unsigned int n)
{
    return foo(n - 1) + std::to_string(n) + foo(n - 1);
}
```

We can see that the function contains two identical elements **foo(n - 1)** - so we could optimize it:

```
std::string foo(unsigned int n)
{
    std::string s_prev = foo(n - 1);
    return s_prev + std::to_string(n) + s_prev;
}
```

Almost all. We need to tell this cyclic machine when to stop, otherwise, it will come out in the negative area! We must stop when n == 0:

```
std::string foo(unsigned int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return std::string(" ");
    std::string s_prev = foo(n - 1);
    return s_prev + std::to_string(n) + s_prev;
}
```

That's all!

Comment: Thank You @snake_style, I went with

    void nth(int n){
        if(n == 0) return;
        nth(n-1);
        std::cout << n;
        nth(n-1);
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return;
    foo(n-1); printf("%d ",n); foo(n-1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo(4);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```